# Converting Varchar (1/24/15 1:30:00 PM) to date format (2015-01-24 13:30:00)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this date format : 1/24/15 1:30:00 PM(Varchar), but I want to convert it changing into datetime format (2015-02-24 13:30:00) using query, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1/24/15 1:30:00 PM', '%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p')
FROM yourTable
```

If you don't like the format of the output this gives you, you can force it to what you want by wrapping `STR_TO_DATE()` in a call to `DATE_FORMAT()`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('1/24/15 1:30:00 PM', '%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p'),
                   '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: can you explain it, I was accidentally just using 
STR_TO_DATE('1/24/15 1:30:00 PM', '%m/%d/%y %h:%i:%s %p')
somehow it worked too

Comment: You might be able to just use `STR_TO_DATE()` if you are happy with what the output looks like.  If you don't like that output, you can wrap it in `DATE_FORMAT()` to get any output style you want.